# can i insert rich 4 tree comonent and leave other componenets in 3.3?

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I am having big issues with rich:tree in 3.3 version but the all application is written in 4 therefor refactoring all the system is not advise can i take just tree  component from 4 ?...

Answer (score 0):

You either use 3.x or 4.x for everything, mixing them is probably not possible.